# marshal an array to a single xml element in go

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I'm learning Go by writing a program that generates files in [Collada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA) format, which describes geometry using XML.

You annotate your structs and almost everything works as you'd expect, except I can't figure out how to marshal arrays into one XML element - I always end up generating N elements.

In other words, I'd like

```
<input>
    <p>0 1 2</p>
</input>
```

instead of

```
<input>
    <p>0</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
</input>
```

The code is as follows

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type Vert struct {
        XMLName xml.Name    `xml:"input"`
        Indices     []int   `xml:"p"`
    }

    v := &Vert{Indices:[]int{0, 1, 2}}
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(v, "", "    ")
    if err == nil {
        os.Stdout.Write(output)
    }
}
```

Various comments (and code) from [encoding/xml/marshal.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/xml/marshal.go) seem to imply that I'm out of luck:

> // Marshal handles an array or slice by marshalling each of the elements.
>   // Slices and arrays iterate over the elements. They do not have an enclosing tag.

Strangely, if I change my array type to uint8, the array is not marshalled at all.

If I am out of luck, I'll probably use the xml:",innerxml" annotation to substitute the array myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, encoding/xml will not be able to do this out-of-the-box.  You can do something like this instead:

```
import (
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Vert struct {
    P string `xml:"p"`
}

func (v *Vert) SetIndices(indices []int) {
    s := make([]string, len(indices))
    for i := range indices {
        s[i] = strconv.FormatInt(int64(indices[i]), 10)
    }
    v.P = strings.Join(s, " ")
}
```

**EDIT:** I originally wrote a getter instead of setter.

Comment: Isn't this for unmarshalling _from_ XML?

Comment: Aaaaa you're right.  Serves me right for trying to answer questions on SO late at night. :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did my own xml marshalling for this type of array,
by changing the type to `string` and using the `innerxml` attribute.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

func MyMarshalArray(indices []int) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer

    buffer.WriteString("<p>")
    for i := 0; i < len(indices); i++ {
        buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%v ", indices[i]))
    }
    buffer.WriteString("</p>")
    return buffer.String()
}

func main() {
    type Vert struct {
        XMLName xml.Name    `xml:"input"`
        Indices     string  `xml:",innerxml"`
    }

    v := &Vert{Indices:MyMarshalArray([]int{0, 1, 2})}
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(v, "", "    ")
    if err == nil {
        os.Stdout.Write(output)
    }
}
```